# Android: View not shown on first time after install

Tags: android, view, invisible

I have an Activity which uses a ViewSwitcher to show a loading screen and then my main view. The loading screen is shown ok but the main view is invisible. It is there because I can not touch anything on the screen after my app is started but it is invisible. I need to navigate to the home screen (the system bar is still active) and then restart the app which just brings it to the foreground (makes it visible).

This only happens on the first open after the installation. I have tried to set the visibility manually and to bring it to the foreground with bringToFront() but it stays invisible until I tap the app icon again.

This is my code:
I start a loading AsyncTask and in *onPreExecute* I do this:

```
viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(MainActivity.this);  
viewSwitcher.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.splashscreen, null));  
setContentView(viewSwitcher);
mv = new MainView(MainActivity.this);
```

then in *doInBackground* i do all my heavy loading and in *onPostExecute* I switch the view like this:

```
viewSwitcher.addView(mv);
viewSwitcher.showNext();
//I have tried all this:
mv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
viewSwitcher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
viewSwitcher.bringToFront();
mv.bringToFront();
```

I have also tried to set the content view normally without the content switcher but to no avail. It is like the UI is just not invalidated after the async task. I don't know why this only happens once after the installation and works fine every other time.

Comment: Have you tried setting the contentView before you do anything in async task, ie set it immediately after super.onCreate().

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just tried, doesn't make a difference. The weird thing is that the first view of the viewSwitcher is displayed fine, just the second one is invisible. And only on the first time.

Comment: I have a similar problem with a couple of views defined in XML. They do not appear on first run of the app after a new install. Then after that they always show. On Sony Experia ST25i with 4.0.4. Android bug?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out. The problem was an error during the loading and accessing the asyncTask to update the progress. That error was handled so the loading continued but this somehow made the view invisible. I put myasyncTask.setProgress() in runOnUiThread and viola, the view loaded and showed as expected.